# Finding the sum of the coefficients for $P(x) = (4x^5-3x^3-2x+1)^{1000000}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Let $P(x) = (4x^5-3x^3-2x+1)^{1000000}$. Determine the sum of the coefficients and find the constant term.

I tried to approach this using Vieta's in order to find the coefficients, but that didn't seem to work. What might be the trick here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the coefficients of a polynomial can be found by substituting in $1$ for the variable. For the constant term, substitute in $0.$

Comment: Ah! The sum is then $4 + (-3) + (-2) = -1$ and the constant term $1$?

Comment: Not quite. You forgot to add the constant term in the first computation. Yes, the constant term is 1. In any case, be sure to prove this result by substituting in 1 and 0 into the general form of a univariate polynomial so that you fully understand why this works.

Comment: So even though in the first computation the constant term isn't a coefficient of any variable it should be added?

Comment: Yes, it should be added. In my experience, the constant term is considered to be a "coefficient" because it is the coefficient of the $x^0$ term even though we don't ordinarily write it that way.